# ECMA 6 postfix condition use-cases

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, ecmascript-6

I was reading the following [presentation](https://speakerdeck.com/polarblau/coffeescript-vs-ecmascript-6), and somewhere towards the end it mentions Postfix Conditions to be introduced in ECMA6 script. It provides he following use-case scenario:

```
console.log("42") if question is true;
```

I searched Google for more use-case scenarios and potential advantages to regular conditions.

What was the reason for introducing it?

Does the postfix condition target only 'one-liner' scenarios as in the example above, or are there more involved use-cases for it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You got it wrong. Postfix conditional won't be a part of ES6, that's a feature of CoffeeScript. In presentation they are mentioned in *What's missing? [from ES6 that is present in CoffeeScript]* section. Also there is no `is` operator in JavaScript, neither it is planned for ES6/ES7.

Comment: Thank you and sorry for confusion on my side :) No wonder Google didn't produce any meaningful search results.